# Python only keeps the last line

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, save, line

I am trying to build a dictionary with a csv file.

The csv file is this:

> nombre,cajones,precio "Lima",100,32.20 "Naranja",50,91.10
> "Caqui",150,83.44 "Mandarina",200,51.23 "Durazno",95,40.37
> "Uva",50,65.10 "Limon",100,70.44

My code is:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

def leer_camion(nombre_archivo):
    camion=[]
    registro={}
    with open(nombre_archivo,"rt") as f:
        filas = csv.reader(f)
        encabezado = next(filas)
        for fila in filas:
            registro[encabezado[0]] = fila[0]
            registro[encabezado[1]] = int(fila[1])
            registro[encabezado[2]] = float(fila[2])
            camion.append(registro)
    return camion

camion = leer_camion('camion.csv')
pprint(camion)
```

The memory of Python only saves the last line. the result is:

```
[{'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44},
 {'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44},
 {'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44},
 {'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44},
 {'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44},
 {'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44},
 {'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44}]
```

Always the same fruit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.copy()` when you are appending. Then the reference will not get changed.

```
from pprint import pprint
   
def leer_camion(nombre_archivo):
    camion=[]
    registro={}
    with open(nombre_archivo,"rt") as f:
        filas = csv.reader(f)
        encabezado = next(filas)
        for fila in filas:
            registro[encabezado[0]] = fila[0]
            registro[encabezado[1]] = int(fila[1])
            registro[encabezado[2]] = float(fila[2])
            camion.append(registro.copy())
    return camion
   
camion = leer_camion('camion.csv')
pprint(camion)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! But i have another problem. That code chages the order of the elements. It appears the second element first. Like  this:                                           
            [{'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Lima', 'precio': 32.2},
 {'cajones': 50, 'nombre': 'Naranja', 'precio': 91.1},
 {'cajones': 150, 'nombre': 'Caqui', 'precio': 83.44},
 {'cajones': 200, 'nombre': 'Mandarina', 'precio': 51.23},
 {'cajones': 95, 'nombre': 'Durazno', 'precio': 40.37},
 {'cajones': 50, 'nombre': 'Uva', 'precio': 65.1},
 {'cajones': 100, 'nombre': 'Limon', 'precio': 70.44}]